# Close webview on success event of ajax function

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to close my webview or redirect to lets say `MainActivity.Java` when i get successful event from Ajax function.

**Let me explain..**

On click event of button I call this `WebviewActivity.java` via intent. Now I have php file which I load into webview via `webview.loadUrl()`. Now user will come on this page and enter their details and when press ok their data will get inserted into page via ajax call of php file.On successful ajax call that `div<div>` tag will get hide and another `<div>` tag will get display which contain one message "Your details has been recorded." Now i have put `onBackPress()` so user will get back on `MainActivity.java`. But instead of that I want something like after successful event webview get close automatically or get redirect to `MainActivity.java` automatically. Is it possible to do that kind of thing? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

here is code of webview.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar urTollbar;
WebView webView;
String parsringUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    urTollbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.URanim_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(urTollbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Submit For Approval");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    parsringUrl =  getIntent().getStringExtra("ParsingURL");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(parsringUrl);




}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    Intent intent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a java function from javascript in webview.

**Java**

The Java methods are exposed to Javascript with a special class. Here is an example. The exposed methods are annotated with @JavascriptInterface annotation. The documentation says the annotation is mandatory for API level 17 and above. I’m not sure, but I think before SDK 17 all the methods are exposed.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Add the class to webview with

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");
```

The first parameter is the interface class with the context and the latter is the variable name to be used in Javascript.

**Javascript**

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        if(typeof android !== "undefined" && android !== null) {
            android.showToast(toast);
        } else {
            alert("Not viewing in webview");
        }
    }
</script>
```

In Javascript there is a global object called Android. The object name comes from the addJavascriptInterface method. That object has all the methods annotated in the interface class, in this example showToast(String toast). The if statement is there to check if the object is set. With this if statement the site can be used from other browsers as well where the Android interface doesn’t exist.

Comment: Where I have to use "android" variable in java script which is define on android side?
  `myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");`

Comment: "android" is a global variable in opening website in webview, so you can use anywhere. You can use it in ajax request success callback method.

Comment: ok so how would i able to close this webview or redirect user to `MainActivity.java` page? And Thank you mate.. :)

Comment: In WebAppInterface class, you can take reference of activity that contains WebView, and finish that activity, after start MainActivity.

Comment: Ok, Got what I want. Once again thank you so much for helping me. :)